# Linq To Sql Convert

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have query in `linq` and I want to convert that query in sql I am not very good in linq so can anyone help me to convert this query in sql:
We have ticket table and issues table ticket id is referenced in issue table :

```
var tickets = tickets.Where(x => x.Issues.Where(y => y.ResolutionDetails == "Resolved" &&
                                y.ResolvedwithSupplierDate == null).Count() == x.Issues.Count() && x.Issues.Count() > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: What does it mean convert to SQL? You don't know how to monitor EF SQL Queries? Or you just need to rewrite this query to be effective?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I know how to monitor EF queries but I didn't understand this query 
specially the count part in end why comparing the count and why nested where is this not done by joins ?

Comment: When you execute this query you should visit SQL profiler to get the defined query

Answer (score 3):

I hope this rewritten query will help you to understand what this query do:

```cs
var tickets = tickets.Where(x => 
        x.Issues.All(y => y.ResolutionDetails == "Resolved" 
           && y.ResolvedwithSupplierDate == null) 
        && x.Issues.Any()
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: query is taking 20 seconds to execute even for 500 records

Comment: Original query is faster?

Comment: no same it is slow as well

Comment: Create new question, how to optimise this LINQ Query. Show model classes and indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this tool - https://www.linqpad.net/. It may not be straightforward without setting up your data but perhaps may help. I think that changing the EF core logging levels may also help to see the SQL generated. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging)
This is not an answer as such but just some suggestions. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to get the ticket where the resolution of the ticket is not equal to 0 and the ticket resolution count is equal to resolved count.
it uses the resolved as resolved tag. If it is not resolved then the resolvewithsupplier date would be null

Sql should be something like

```
select * from tickets where (select count(Id) from Issues where TicketId = Ticket.Id <> 0
and ((select count(Id) from Issues Where TicketId = Ticket.Id) = (select count(Id) from Issues 
Where TicketId and Ticket.Id = 'Resolved' and ResolvedwithSupplierDate is null)))
```